# GitLab Pages deployment step fails after successfull build

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to host a reveal.js presentation via gitlab pages. The repository can be found here: https://gitlab.com/JanGregor/demo-slides

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` is fairly simple:

```
image: node:4.2.2

pages:
  cache:
    paths:
    - node_modules/
  script:
  - npm install
  - node_modules/.bin/gulp
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - build
  only:
  - master
```

After a commit to master though, something goes wrong. The pages task itself is [executed and runs just fine](https://gitlab.com/JanGregor/demo-slides/-/jobs/27714275). It even shows in the logs that my build directory has been scanned and that the artefacts have been found.

Oddly, the subsequent `pages:deploy` task fails. It only says :

> pages failed to extract

Any help would be greatly appreciated, since I have no clue where to look to next. The documentation itself isn't really helpful when trying to implement an deployment flow with npm.

Thanks in advance folks !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apparently a page can only be published from a folder in under the artifacts that is called "public".

Answer (score 9):

From the [GitLab Pages documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/introduction.html#quick-start):

> To make use of GitLab Pages, the contents of `.gitlab-ci.yml` must follow the rules below:
>
> 1. A special job named `pages` must be defined
> 2. Any static content which will be served by GitLab Pages must be placed under a `public/` directory
> 3. `artifacts` with a path to the `public/` directory must be defined

Also mentioned (somewhat tangentially) in the ["GitLab Pages from A to Z" guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/getting_started_part_four.html#the-public-directory):

> ... and GitLab Pages will only consider files in a directory called `public`.

Comment: Since I did not want a folder called `public` in my repo, I told the `pages` task to create a `public` dir and copy the files there.

Comment: Yes the job must exactly be named `pages`, it's possible to use many sub-tasks `pages:data`, `pages:docs`, etc. but in the end it's mandatory that the final task that will upload / deploy is named `pages`, the other sub-tasks can't deploy just build artifacts that are shared among the sub-jobs.